# Why do i have to have "vkClearValue" in my code to make it work correctly?

Tags: vulkan

I have some base c++/vulkan code (windows 10, 64):

```cpp
#define LOG(x) std::cout << "CONSOLE_LOG: " << ##x << std::endl

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "xgk-vulkan-wrappers.h"
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32
#include "glfw3.h"
#include <glfw3native.h>

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 800

const char* instance_layers[1] = { "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation" };
const char* instance_exts[3] = { "VK_KHR_surface", "VK_KHR_win32_surface", VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME };
const char* device_exts[1] = { VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME };
float queuePriorities[] = { 1.0f };

int main() {
  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::Library library;

  VkApplicationInfo app_info = {};
    app_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    app_info.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

  VkInstanceCreateInfo inst_info = {};
    inst_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    inst_info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;
    inst_info.enabledLayerCount = 1;
    inst_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = instance_layers;
    inst_info.enabledExtensionCount = 3;
    inst_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = instance_exts;

  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::Instance instance(&library, &inst_info);

  std::vector<XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::PhysicalDevice> devs = instance.enumDevs();

  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::PhysicalDevice phys_dev = devs[0];
    phys_dev.getQueueFamilyProps();

  VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queue_info = {};
    queue_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
    queue_info.queueFamilyIndex = 0;
    queue_info.queueCount = 1;
    queue_info.pQueuePriorities = queuePriorities;

  VkDeviceCreateInfo dev_info = {};
    dev_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
    dev_info.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
    dev_info.pQueueCreateInfos = &queue_info;
    dev_info.enabledExtensionCount = 1;
    dev_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = device_exts;

  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::Device dev(&instance, &phys_dev, &dev_info);

  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::Queue present_queue(&dev, 0, 0);

  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::Queue graphics_queue(&dev, 0, 0);

  glfwInit();

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "test_vulkan", nullptr, nullptr);
  glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, instance.handle);

  VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR win32_surface_info = {};
    win32_surface_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WIN32_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    win32_surface_info.hinstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    win32_surface_info.hwnd = glfwGetWin32Window(window);

  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::SurfaceKHR surfaceKHR(&instance, &win32_surface_info);

  phys_dev.getSurfaceSupportKHR(&surfaceKHR, 0);
  phys_dev.getSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(&surfaceKHR);
  phys_dev.getSurfaceFormatsKHR(&surfaceKHR);

  const uint32_t queueFamilyIndices[1] = { 0 };

  VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapchain_info = {};
    swapchain_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    swapchain_info.surface = surfaceKHR.handle;
    swapchain_info.minImageCount = 3;
    swapchain_info.imageFormat = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    swapchain_info.imageColorSpace = VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR;
    swapchain_info.imageExtent = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };
    swapchain_info.imageArrayLayers = 1;
    swapchain_info.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT;
    swapchain_info.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    swapchain_info.queueFamilyIndexCount = 1;
    swapchain_info.pQueueFamilyIndices = queueFamilyIndices;
    swapchain_info.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    swapchain_info.preTransform = VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR;
    swapchain_info.compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
    swapchain_info.presentMode = VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR;
    swapchain_info.clipped = VK_TRUE;

  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::SwapchainKHR swapchainKHR(&dev, &swapchain_info);

  std::vector<VkImage> images = swapchainKHR.getImages();

  std::vector<XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::ImageView> image_views;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
    VkImageViewCreateInfo image_view_info = {};
      image_view_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
      image_view_info.image = images[i];
      image_view_info.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
      image_view_info.format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
      image_view_info.components.r = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
      image_view_info.components.g = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
      image_view_info.components.b = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
      image_view_info.components.a = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
      image_view_info.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
      image_view_info.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
      image_view_info.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
      image_view_info.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
      image_view_info.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

    XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::ImageView image_view(&dev, &image_view_info);

    image_views.push_back(image_view);
  }

  VkAttachmentReference color_attachment_ref = {};
    color_attachment_ref.attachment = 0;
    color_attachment_ref.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

  VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
    subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpass.pColorAttachments = &color_attachment_ref;

  VkAttachmentDescription color_attachment = {};
    color_attachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    color_attachment.format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    color_attachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    color_attachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    color_attachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    color_attachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    color_attachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    color_attachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

  VkSubpassDependency dependency = {};
    dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
    dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
    dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;

  VkRenderPassCreateInfo render_pass_info = {};
    render_pass_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    render_pass_info.attachmentCount = 1;
    render_pass_info.pAttachments = &color_attachment;
    render_pass_info.subpassCount = 1;
    render_pass_info.pSubpasses = &subpass;
    render_pass_info.dependencyCount = 1;
    render_pass_info.pDependencies = &dependency;

  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::RenderPass render_pass(&dev, &render_pass_info);

  std::vector<XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::Framebuffer> framebuffers;
  std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> vk_command_buffers;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < image_views.size(); i++) {
    VkFramebufferCreateInfo framebuffer_info = {};
      framebuffer_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
      framebuffer_info.renderPass = render_pass.handle;
      framebuffer_info.attachmentCount = 1;
      framebuffer_info.pAttachments = &image_views[i].handle;
      framebuffer_info.width = WIDTH;
      framebuffer_info.height = HEIGHT;
      framebuffer_info.layers = 1;

    XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::Framebuffer framebuffer(&dev, &framebuffer_info);

    framebuffers.push_back(framebuffer);

    VkCommandBuffer vk_command_buffer;

    vk_command_buffers.push_back(vk_command_buffer);
  }

  VkCommandPoolCreateInfo command_pool_info = {};
    command_pool_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_INFO;
    command_pool_info.queueFamilyIndex = 0;

  XGK_VULKAN_WRAPPERS::CommandPool command_pool(&dev, &command_pool_info);

  VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo alloc_info = {};
    alloc_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    alloc_info.commandPool = command_pool.handle;
    alloc_info.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    alloc_info.commandBufferCount = 3;

  command_pool.alloc(&alloc_info, vk_command_buffers.data());

  VkClearColorValue clear_color = { 0, 1, 0, 1 };

  VkCommandBufferBeginInfo command_buffer_begin_info = {};
    command_buffer_begin_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    command_buffer_begin_info.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;

  VkImageSubresourceRange image_range = {};
    image_range.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    image_range.baseMipLevel = 0;
    image_range.levelCount = 1;
    image_range.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    image_range.layerCount = 1;

  VkClearValue test_clear_color = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };

  for (size_t i = 0; i < image_views.size(); i++) {
    VkImageMemoryBarrier clear_barier = {};
      clear_barier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
      clear_barier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
      clear_barier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
      clear_barier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
      clear_barier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
      clear_barier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = 0;
      clear_barier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = 0;
      clear_barier.image = images[i];
      clear_barier.subresourceRange = image_range;

    VkImageMemoryBarrier present_barier = {};
      present_barier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
      present_barier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
      present_barier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
      present_barier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
      present_barier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
      present_barier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = 0;
      present_barier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = 0;
      present_barier.image = images[i];
      present_barier.subresourceRange = image_range;

    dev.vkBeginCommandBuffer(vk_command_buffers[i], &command_buffer_begin_info);
    dev.vkCmdPipelineBarrier(vk_command_buffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &clear_barier);
    dev.vkCmdClearColorImage(vk_command_buffers[i], images[i], VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, &clear_color, 1, &image_range);
    dev.vkCmdPipelineBarrier(vk_command_buffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &present_barier);
    dev.vkEndCommandBuffer(vk_command_buffers[i]);
  }

  VkSemaphore image_available_semaphore;
  VkSemaphore render_finished_semaphore;

  VkSemaphoreCreateInfo
    semaphore_info = {};
    semaphore_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SEMAPHORE_CREATE_INFO;

  vkCreateSemaphore(dev.handle, &semaphore_info, nullptr, &image_available_semaphore);
  vkCreateSemaphore(dev.handle, &semaphore_info, nullptr, &render_finished_semaphore);

  VkPipelineStageFlags wait_stages[1] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT };

  VkSubmitInfo
    submit_info = {};
    submit_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submit_info.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submit_info.pWaitSemaphores = &image_available_semaphore;
    submit_info.pWaitDstStageMask = wait_stages;
    submit_info.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submit_info.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submit_info.pSignalSemaphores = &render_finished_semaphore;

  VkPresentInfoKHR
    present_info_KHR = {};
    present_info_KHR.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
    present_info_KHR.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    present_info_KHR.pWaitSemaphores = &render_finished_semaphore;
    present_info_KHR.swapchainCount = 1;
    present_info_KHR.pSwapchains = &swapchainKHR.handle;

  uint32_t image_index;

  while (true) {
    swapchainKHR.acquireNextImage(0xffffffff, image_available_semaphore, VK_NULL_HANDLE, image_index);

    submit_info.pCommandBuffers = &vk_command_buffers[image_index];

    graphics_queue.submit(1, &submit_info);

    present_info_KHR.pImageIndices = &image_index;

    present_queue.presentKHR(&present_info_KHR);

    dev.waitIdle();
  }

  vkDestroySemaphore(dev.handle, image_available_semaphore, nullptr);
  vkDestroySemaphore(dev.handle, render_finished_semaphore, nullptr);

  command_pool.destroy();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < framebuffers.size(); i++) {
    framebuffers[i].destroy();
  }

  render_pass.destroy();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < image_views.size(); i++) {
    image_views[i].destroy();
  }

  swapchainKHR.destroy();
  surfaceKHR.destroy();

  glfwDestroyWindow(window);
  glfwTerminate();

  dev.destroy(); 
  instance.destroy(); 
  library.destroy();

  return 0;
};
```

Here is one excess line in the code:

"VkClearValue test_clear_color = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };"

This object is never used in the code, only is declared. But if i remove or comment this line, the code execution fails on the graphics queue submisson.

Did anybody face this strange behavior? What is the problem?

Comment: Uninitialized variable somewhere may cause that. Run the compiler in Debug mode, and it should crash more deterministically.

Comment: Use Validation Layers. You are enabling the appropriate layer and extension, but you are not creating a debug callback in the above code. Or just use `VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` env for convenience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use validation layer, i just removed the pieces, related to it, to minimize the code in my question. But layer shows nothing with that execution crashing. I have already faced with such a layer behavior, when i tried to record command buffers, which i did not allocate previously. Execution crashed without any information. Do you know how to make the layer show most detailed info?

Comment: Layers can't catch all application errors. Even if validation is clean, operations still may fail. What is the actual error you get on queue submission? Does it crash? If so, what's on the call stack? If it doesn't crash but returns a VkResult, what result does it return?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! The problem was in the uninitialized variable "image_index". But it is so strange, that some variable may affect queue submission. I need to learn more about it.

Comment: @DenisBelov Undefined behavior is undefined.